# What is the best clean way to handle three datasets with different size for a training neural net?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, pytorch

I have three datasets,each has different lengths. I have a model with three input pipeline (similar to Siamese, but three input pipeline) and therefore, I have to separately feed the data. I cannot concatenate them. The first one has around 600 ,second one has 3000 and last one has 40000 samples. In each training loop, I want to go through them and feed them into my model.

I defined three datasets and three dataloaders in pytorch; however, I am not sure how to iterate over them?

In the case of two, I have tried cycle over the smaller dataset and worked. But it is not working for three.

```
for step, ((images_Di, labels_Di),(images_Dj, labels_Dj)) in enumerate(zip(loader_D2, cycle(loader_D1))):
```

I appreciate if any one help me how is best way to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have 3 different datasets/loaders? If the sizes of elements in each dataset are the same, then you can just concatenate images and labels from all datasets and create one pytorch dataset and loader. Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @StanisławWilczyński. Since the size of input and number of classes are different for each dataset, therefore I can not concatenate them.